# Getting an error with react native, expo and realm saying " Error: Getting '$$typeof' from binding before it was injected " How do I stop this?

Tags: react-native, expo, realm

So I am trying to use realm in my expo project, so I did the command `npx expo prebuild` and got the android folder installed in my project. I runned the code and recieved the error 'Error: Getting '$$typeof' from binding before it was injected, js engine: hermes'. Also when I ran prebuild I only got the android folder but not the ios folder.

I tried running it on an apple and an android device, they both showed the same errors. I was expecting the error to be cleared on the android device because it seems like an android device.

Comment: I would say a step was missed when setting up/configuration. Please review [Install the React Native SDK](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/install/#use-the-sdk-with-expo) and then in particular [Use the SDK with Expo](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/install/#use-the-sdk-with-expo). There could potentially be a version compatibility issue so ensure the installed versions meet the minimum.

Comment: still getting an error